# Dropdown not working in html with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm having a bit of an issue where my dropdown won't work using bootstrap.
The dropdown only appears from screens smaller than the $md variable.

The issue is when I click the dropdown icon it doesn't seem to be working
I have the HTML code below but if you want the whole project take a look at this [Github repo](https://github.com/michiel2003/Project_SOF)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Sass-Bootstrap Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary ">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-primary_invert px-3" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-primary_invert" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link text-primary_invert" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-primary_invert" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-primary_invert" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled text-primary_invert" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  

  <script src="/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use `navbar-expand-xl` instead of `navbar-expand-lg` as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7jn4pga/

Comment: @GrafiCode That doesn't really solve my issue of the dropdown straight up not working. changing it to navbrar-expand-xl  just changes at what size the dropdown is visible

Comment: You said «The dropdown only appears from screens smaller than the $md variable.» that should address this problem at least. About the «when I click the dropdown icon it doesn't seem to be working», how can we reproduce this? do you see errors in console?

Comment: nope, no errors. What I mean is that a button appears (on smaller screens like tablets or phones) and upon clicking this button the items which are normally visible should appear.

Comment: @GrafiCode you can reproduce this by taking a look at this  [Gtihub repo](https://github.com/michiel2003/Project_SOF)

Comment: I don't see any javascript library in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the JQuery & Popper.js links

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[more info here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)